# Deactivate composed viewmodel

Tags: durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

There is a lot of questions about this but I cannot find any answer that works with the latest durandal version (2.1.0).

I am showing a child viewmodel inside my page using this:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { model: activeScreen, activationData: {id:selectedId}}"></div>
```

`activeScreen` is an observable to which I pass an string like this: `viewmodels/child`

It works, and the child viewmodel gets activated and shown on the screen. But when I change `activeScreen`, I need the child viewmodel to run `deactivate`. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as your child views are instance modules and not singleton modules, you can move that code to the `detached` handler.  That's what we do as well: All of our child views are managed through dynamic composition, not child routing (which just doesn't work for the enterprise-style app).  The `deactivate` handler comes into play in the context of *routing*.

By *dynamic composition* I'm referring to the swapping in and out of child views/viewModels through an observable.

But, again, the key to making this work is that the child views must be instance modules.  That way they'll actually get unloaded from memory.  If you go with singletons, the modules will never get detached (although there are ways to force this to happen).

Comment: Amazing, I confess that I did not even know abot the existence of `detached` and it worked perfectly for my case too. Thanks!